# Slide Out Menu in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been following this tutorial [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr5JjxnE8yU), I am trying to make a slide out menu, but I get an error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. I believe it has to do with self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SlideMenuView") as! SlideMenuView? but I am not sure, My code is below:

```
class CategoryTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate  {



        @IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: ExpandableTableView!
        var slideMenuVC: SlideMenuView?
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        var categories = [Category]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            menuTableView.allHeadersInitiallyCollapsed = true
            menuTableView.initiallyExpandedSection = 1
            menuTableView.singleSelectionEnable = true
            slideMenuVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SlideMenuView") as! SlideMenuView?
            categoryTableViewCleanUp()
            ref = Database.database().reference()
            loadData()
           // registerForPushNotifications()
        }
        // Menu Table
        func categoryTableViewCleanUp() {
            menuTableView?.delegate = self
            menuTableView?.dataSource = self
        }
        // MARK: Notifications
        /*func getNotificationSettings() {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
                guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
       func registerForPushNotifications() {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
                (granted, error) in
                print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            }
            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        } */
        // MARK: Slideout Menu
        @IBAction func menuAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            // Show menu
            if AppDelegate.slideMenuBool{
                showSlideMenu()
            }
            else {
                closeSlideMenu()
            }

        }
        func showSlideMenu() {
            self.slideMenuVC?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
            self.addChildViewController((slideMenuVC)!)
            self.view.addSubview((slideMenuVC?.view)!)
            AppDelegate.slideMenuBool = false
        }
        func closeSlideMenu() {
            self.slideMenuVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            AppDelegate.slideMenuBool = true
        }
```

Comment: SlideMenuView is this identifier match with storyboard?

Comment: @SaurabhJain I just made the identifier.. now I receive this error: Unknown class SlideMenuView in Interface Builder file.
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController'

Comment: Is SlideMenuView super class is UIViewController, Check carefully

Comment: @SaurabhJain yes, It seems to be working, I thought with this statement: slideMenuVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SlideMenuView") as! SlideMenuView?, it creates the identifier

Comment: If your identifier perfectly match then the exception will go... is it working fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check the storyboard identifier match with your code identifier.

```
  slideMenuVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SlideMenuView") as! SlideMenuView?
```

If the identifier didn't matched then your slideMenuVC comes nil and exception occour.